# Separate or Merge Kafka Consumer and API services together

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

After recently reading about event-based architecture, I wanted to change my architecture into one making use of such strengths.

I have two services that expose an API (crud, graphql), each based around a different entity and using a different database.

However, now whenever someone deletes a certain type of row in service A, I need to delete a coupled row in Service B.

So I added Kafka to my design, and whenever I delete the entity in service A, it publishes a notification message into Kafka.

In service B I am currently consuming the same topic so whenever a new message is received the Service will also handle the deletion of the matching entity, because it already has access that table because the same service already exposes the CRUD API to users.

What I'm not sure about is whether putting the Kafka Consumer and the API together in the same service is a good design. It contradicts the point of single responsibility in micro services, and whether there is an issue in one part of the service, it will likely affect the second.

However, creating a new service will also cause me issues - I will have two different services accessing the same table, and I will have to make sure I always maintain them together, whenever making changes to the table or database.

What is the best practice in a incident such as this? Is it inevitable to have different services have data coupling or is it not so bad to use the same service for two, similar usages.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using Kafka... You could do the same with point-to-point service communication, however (JSON-RPC / gRPC), however.

The real problem you seem to be asking about is dual-writes or race-conditions leading to data inconsistency.

While you could use a single consumer group and one topic-partition to preserve order and locking across consumers interested in those events, that does not lock out **other consumer-groups** from interacting with the database to perform the same action. Therefore, Kafka itself won't help with this problem.

You'll need external, distributed locks (e.g. Zookeeper can be used here) that fence off your database clients while you are performing actions against it.

To the original question, Kafka Connect offers an API and is **also** a Producer and Consumer client (and would be recommended for database interactions). So is Confluent Schema Registry, KSQLdb, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the consumer of your service B would not be considered "a service" or part of the "service", as in that it is not called as part the code which services requests. Yet it does provide functionality that is required for the domain function of your microservice. So yes I would consider the consumer part of the Microservice in terms of team/domain responsibility.

There may be different opinions on if the consumer code should share the same code base/repo as the "service" code. Some people believe that it is better to limit the repo scope to a single "executable", others believe it is beneficial to keep the domain scope and have everything in a single repo. I probably belong to the latter group but do not have a very strong opinion on it. I would argue it is more important to have a central documentation / wiki for the domain that will point to the repos involved etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of situation its better to keep the deployments of consumer and your API service separately,

let's say you have multiple services which have rest API's for example Service A connected to database A and B connected to database B also having rest API, and you want to integrate event based framework by using kafka or any message broker like RabbitMQ.

Note - it does not matter at all whether its a single repo or multiple repos. It only needs to have separate deployments that can handle load based on your usecase.

The deployments of these services should be separate to follow the point of single responsibility in micro services.

Now you might lead to data inconsistencies because since the consumer has a separate deployment you might need it to connect to the database of service A which has a certain type of schema.

In this type of situations its better to have the schema in a single place by creating a package which will create the schema for you and you can export it from there.

both these services i.e. the consumer and your rest API service will import the same db schema.

This will resolve the issue of managing of separate schemas of the tables.